# Java - can I do this = in.readObject()?

Tags: java, serialization, netbeans

I'm learning Serialization and I want to know if I can do:

```
 this = in.readObject();
```

As to serialize it I did:

```
 out.writeObject(this);
```

Or I have to load every single Object in the class from the stream individually?

Comment: @ImmerAllein ain't work, had to use a temp object, then load and store the values. Isn't there a solution similar to what I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a **value**, not a **reference**. It means "The current object." You can't assign a new value to `this`.